# Using "in" in where condition with case

Tags: sql-server, case, where-in

I have a sql table which has one column "type". It has values A,B,C,D. I'm writing a stored procedure in which type is the in parameter @type.

@type can has either value 'A' or 'A,B,C' or 'ALL'  based on user selection on screen. Which means user can select single,multiple or ALL options. I need to filter data from my table with condition on column "type".

I want something similar to below:

```
select * from maintable where
( case when @type ='ALL' then 1=1) else
 type in (select data from SplitString(@type,',')) end)
```

I have written a split function which return values in a table format.

When ALL is selected then the whole table should be returned. When specific type(s) is selected, only those types should be returned.

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: How about using `IF` in your `SP`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM maintable 
WHERE @type ='ALL' OR    
(@type <>'ALL' AND TYPE IN (SELECT data FROM SplitString(@type,','))
```

Comment: It's `STRING_SPLIT()` not `SplitString()`

Comment: @Sami he says this is a UDF that he wrote

Comment: Oh yes my bad :)

Comment: Thanks a lot..It worked.It is so simple and perfect!!

Comment: @Sami , when i tried to use STRING_SPLIT(), it is saying invalid object. That is the reason I have created my own function SplitString().

Comment: STRING_SPLIT() is available for databases with compatibility level 130 or above. This is connected with the version of SQL Server (but even in the new SQL server there can be databases with low compatibility level): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below :

```
if @type ='ALL' 
    set @type ='A,B,C,D'

select * from maintable where
type in (select data from SplitString(@type, ','))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `IF`:

```
IF @type ='ALL'
    SELECT *
    FROM MainTable
        ELSE
            SELECT *
            FROM MainTable
            WHERE Type IN (SELECT data FROM SplitString(@type,',') )
```